# Are there other rational/algebraic term series for $e$, and do any converge faster or are faster to compute than the classical series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We have the classical rational term series $e = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/n!$ which converges incredibly fast. But are there other series for $e$ that have all rational or algebraic terms with closed form expression, and if so, do any of them converge faster than the classical series? Or are faster to compute? I'm guessing there may be other series but the classical one probably converges the fastest (and/or is the fastest to compute) which is why we use it in computation.

Comment: While it might not be faster to calculate, this series converges faster than the series you mentioned $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{(2n)!}+\frac1{(2n + 1)!}\right)$$

Comment: ^How do we know that that series converges to $e$?

Comment: @Darksonn That looks like a trivial example, because it's just grouping together terms of the original series into pairs.

Comment: Perhaps $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$? Or $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$?

Comment: @barakmanos That's not a series.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_representations_of_e

Answer (score 1):

Here's a paper on this precise problem:

http://www.brotherstechnology.com/docs/Improving_Convergence_(CMJ-2004-01).pdf

The gist of their approach is essentially what Darksonn proposed: combining terms.

The conclusions begin:

"Initial findings indicate that when evaluated on a term by term basis, from both the algebraic and computational standpoints, these new series are substantially faster than [the classical series] for computing the digits of $e$."